# is it possible to create a message which has a field with its own type with protocol buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

Is it possible to define a message which has a field of its own type as in linked lists with protocol buffers? For example the value of next field could be null at the end of the list.

```
message Node {
 string name = 1;
 Node next = 2;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned linked list: be aware that protobuf uses a recursive parser so it has a limit on the maximum message depth allowed. By default protobuf limits recursion to 100 messages deep, and language stack sizes provide a hard upper limit.

Comment: The simple answer is "Yes", but I wonder why you don't just try it?

Comment: @jpa you're right, i should give more detail. As in the question's edited version, I mean does it support the operations like setting null values to that field etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked how to make a custom type. The documentation mentions to try to avoid that. I find that you can model almost anything with the parts / types that are built in. To make a list of nodes with the built in types do this:

```
message ResponseOfNodes {
 repeated Node nodes = 1;
}

message Node {
 string name = 1;
 string someOtherData = 2;
}
```

Here's code that uses the generated code / list.

```
// make a node so it can be added to the list. 
Node node1 = Node.newBuilder().setName("a name").setSomeOtherData("etc").build();

// Build a response (ResponseOfNodes) that will get nodes added to its list. Add two Nodes.  
ResponseOfNodes.Builder responseBuilder = ResponseOfNodes.newBuilder().addNodes(node1);
responseBuilder.addNodes(node1.toBuilder().setName("name 2").build());

// build the ResponseOfNodes and print it out. 
ResponseOfNodes responseOfNodes = responseBuilder.build();
log.info("the list: {}", responseOfNodes.getNodesList());
```

Console Output;

```
[INFO ] [main] - Hello I am a client.
[INFO ] [main] - the list: [name: "a name"
someOtherData: "etc"
, name: "name 2"
someOtherData: "etc"
```